# Bootstrap fixed to top navbar covering website

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Because I am using this Navbar as a site editing tool rather than a normal Navbar, I require a solution that doesn't involve editing the Bootstrap code and instead use some type of `style=""` edit instead as I am including the Bootstrap code from elsewhere to make things light, so I can use it on multiple sites.

I am trying to stop the `fixed to top` Navbar from overlaying the top of the website, this is showing the Logo and top links under the Navbar, instead I am looking to try to layer it on top until the user scrolls down where the Navbar will then cover the website as it should on its way down. Here is the code I am using, if anybody can help me find a solution I would be appreciative!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I have attempted to introduce:

`style="padding-top:100px;"` And changed the `px` but with no luck, this then totally covers the top of the websites.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want or do not want to use the `navbar-fixed-top` class? And where you have applied the `style="padding-top: 100px"?

Comment: Sorry, yes I do need to fixed to the top of the site but I am trying to get the entire website (inc the header) to show below the navbar while its fixed to the top without it covering the header. I applied that to the top `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to apply the padding style at the `body` instead the `div`:

```
<body style="padding-top: 100px">
```

It's given in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top :-)

> ### Body padding required
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other
>   content, unless you add `padding` to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your
>   own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is
>   50px high.
>
> `body { padding-top: 70px; }`
>
> Make sure to include this **after** the
>   core Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Amazing how such a big problem can be solved with a minor edit, thanks very much!

Comment: Reading the documentation twice-thrice always helps :-) Feel free to accept the answer.